# Google Drive File Permissions - List Incomplete

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm creating a google drive file programmatically, and assigning `writer` permissions to another user via their email.

When the file is opened the UI shows both users (the creator as owner, and the added writer) in the "share" screen.

When I call `drive.permissions.list({ fileId })` however it returns a list containing only the creator user.

Is this expected?  Why would that not be returning the complete list as shown in the UI?

Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting the API token being used for the `drive.permissions.list({ fileId })` is for the owner of the document.

Comment: what do you mean by "API token" ?

Comment: Sorry, that was confusing, I should have written `access_token`.